# why does mailx -- -f work no longer

Tags: command-line, email

I did the following in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
echo "some body" | mailx -s "some subject" recipient@example.de -- -f sender@example.de
```

it generated a message like this:

```
To: recipient@example.de
Subject: some subject
From: sender@example.de
```

Then I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 and now I get

```
To: -f@example.de, sender@example.de, recipient@example.de
Subject: some subject
From: $ACCOUNTNAME@example.de
```

So, the `-f` is working no longer, and I get a broken email.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

I am using nullmailer.

I am using bsd-mailx.

```
$ ls -l $(which mailx)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Okt 23 23:12 /usr/bin/mailx -> /etc/alternatives/mailx
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/mailx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Okt 23 23:12 /etc/alternatives/mailx -> /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
```

Comment: The manual of `mailx` says that `-f file` is to *read* mail from an alternate file... not to set the "From:" field. I really do not know if it's a recent change...

Comment: @Rmano: yeah, but the `--` should cancel processing of command line arguments and forward the following arguments to sendmail/nullmailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I can set the `From:` header manually with `-a $EXTRAHEADER` and drop the `-- -f` thing:

```
echo "some body" | mailx -s "some subject" recipient@example.de -a "From: sender@example.de"
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful, I could not find this workaround anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a security patch in early January changed the behavior for `--`.

From the changelog at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bsd-mailx/8.1.2-0.20111106cvs-1ubuntu0.1

> bsd-mailx (8.1.2-0.20111106cvs-1ubuntu0.1) precise-security;
>   urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: shell command injection
>
>   - Apply OpenBSD patches from Todd Miller (taken from Debian update):
>
>     - 80-remove_T.patch (remove undocumented/obsolete -T option)
>     - 81-minus_f.patch (adjust -f processing)
>     - 82-expandaddr.patch (fix CVE-2014-7844)
>     - 83-nosendmail.patch (make -- work for option parsing suppression)
>   - CVE-2014-7844  -- Marc Deslauriers    Mon, 05 Jan 2015 11:40:44 -0500

Your workaround is correct, the -a option is best for setting the From header.

I still have a problem where the `-f` option set the Return-Path header, which I did not have any luck doing with `-a`.  I got this from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/list.postfix.users/0AmocPqLUZo

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (provided by postfix) instead of the `mail` command that linked to `bsd-mailx` on my system:

```
echo -e "Subject:some subject\n\nsome body" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -r "sender@example.com" "recipient@example.de"
```

Three things to consider:

- Use  `-r` to specify the return path (and from-address)
- There is no `-s` for the subject. Instead, add the `Subject:` mail header in the `printf` followed by two newlines `\n\n`
- Your `echo` really needs to output the two newlines, not the characters `\n\n`, thus you need `echo -e`